# The bookmark layout is strange

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you see, when I click the "about" the focus moved to the expected position

But the "projects" bookmark is out of my expectation.

[image]

[image]

The content html

```
<span id="projects"></span>
<div class="projects">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="head">PROJECTS</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

<span id="team"></span>
<div class="team">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="head">About Us</h2>
      </div>
```

The nav html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar-scroll" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">VIVOTEK DQA</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#service">Service</a>
            </li>
            <!-- %li -->
            <!-- %a{href: "#feature"} Feature -->
            <!-- %li -->
            <!-- %a{href: "#portfolio"} Portfolio -->
            <li>
              <a href="#team">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <!-- %li -->
            <!-- %a{href: "#ptable"} Pricing -->
            <!-- %li -->
            <!-- %a{href: "#contact"} Contact Us -->
            <li>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right form-inline" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search any automation tools" type="text">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">GO!</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You have a CSS tag but havent provided any CSS, which is likely the issue- can you provide CSS and maybe a jsfiddle.net or site link?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and suggest there's something in your CSS that's different between `<div class="projects">` and `<div class="team">`. You can use your browser's developer tools to see what it is.

Comment: I wanna show you guy the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x4G2n/ but I use rails it includes lots of files

Comment: All we need to see is the HTML, CSS and JS the backend outputs.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned it is likely that your css is different.
Without seeing it have you thought about giving both spans the same class? preferably the one that works as you like it to?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my stupid,

I forgot to add the padding effect to the projects region

```
/* Projects CSS */
.projects{
    padding: 40px 0;
    /*box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;*/
}
```

other regions has the 40px padding